# FFmpeg: Live streaming using RSTP C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, streaming

I want to receive video stream from camera, process it using openCV (for tests - draw red rectangle) and live stream result.

I already can read camera frames, convert to openCV Mat and change them back to AVFrame.

From console im starting rtsp server using: ffplay -rtsp_flags listen -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:8765/live.sdp
Problem shows when im trying call avio_open();

```
av_register_all();
avformat_network_init();
avcodec_register_all();
(...)
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outputContext, NULL, "rtsp", outputPath.c_str());
outputFormat = outputContext->oformat;

cout << "Codec = " << avcodec_get_name(outputFormat->video_codec) << endl;

if (outputFormat->video_codec != AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
    videoStream = add_stream(outputContext, &outputVideoCodec, outputFormat->video_codec);
}
char errorBuff[80];
int k = avio_open(&outputContext->pb, outputPath.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
if (k < 0) {
    cout << "code: " << k << endl;
    fprintf(stderr, "%s \n", av_make_error_string(errorBuff, 80, k));
}

if (avformat_write_header(outputContext, NULL) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when writing header");
}
```

}

Where outputPath = "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8765/live.sdp"
avformat_alloc_output_context2 returns 0, but avio_open < 0 so app prints:

code: -1330794744

Protocol not found

I have no idea what is wrong. I am using ffmpeg build from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ 64-bit Dev

Answer (score 0):

Enable the file protocol by doing:

```
--enable-protocol=file
```

Comment: I tried compile ffmpeg under Windows using github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite but i got .a library files and if i link them in visual studio im getting wall of LNK errors ex. libavutil.a(timecode.o) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __mingw_vsnprintf After research i found that i should link also libmingw32.a and libmingwex.a libraries. I did it, and got another tons of errors like: c:\build\autobuildffmpeg\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdlib.h(306)‌​: error C2059: syntax error: '__declspec(nothrow)'

Comment: Have you tried looking at the links at the end which mention how to build mingw for ffmpeg? - That link appears to be broken though. See this guide: http://www.gooli.org/blog/building-ffmpeg-for-windows-with-msys-and-mingw/ and follow the remaining steps mentioned on jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite

Comment: No i didn't try it. I will follow this guide and inform about result. Unfortunately i can do it tomorrow.

Comment: No problem hopefully it should resolve your issue :)

Comment: I tried follow guide, but i had some problems with Windows, but -thanks to you- i found another possibilty. I installed ubuntu on virtual box and followed this guide: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/blog/?p=414 
Now i am cross-compiling ffmpeg using ./configure --enable-memalign-hack --arch=x86 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --prefix=... (...) --enable-protocol=file 
I will inform what i got :)

Comment: That should work yes, key here though the enable-protocol=file is important :)

Comment: I built ffmpeg with --enable-protocol=file but same error still appears: Protocol not found :(

Comment: Can you check if the muxers and codecs are enabled?

Comment: ffmpeg -codecs: 
D.V.LS h264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
DEV.L. mpeg4 MPEG-4 part 2
(mpeg4 is codec detected by avformat_alloc_output_context2)

ffmpeg -formats:
DE rtsp RTSP output

ffmpeg -protocols:
Input/Output: file

Comment: What is the error code now? is it still -1330794744 or it has changed?

Comment: Also in the formats I dont see mp4 - you can check which ones you can enable by --list-demuxers and enable the required one by --enable-demuxer=demuxer-from-list

Comment: Error code is still -1330794744. In ffmpeg -formats i have [D  mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 QuickTime / MOV ] and [ E mp4  MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14) ](and ipod mp4 + psp mp4 - but i think that is not important now). In --list-demuxers i dont have mp4

Comment: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mov_002fmp4_002f3gp_002fQuickTime section 3.11 mentions the mp4 demux. 'mov' seems to be the demux for the mp4 and a few other formats.

Comment: Then should be ok. ffmpeg -formats returns that MOV is demuxer for mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 and that mp4 is muxer for mp4.

Comment: Add this before char errorBuff[80]; open_video(outputContext,&outputVideoCodec,videoStream); which opens the video codec and buffer initialization etc. Open video function here: http://pastebin.com/TDZ9hMW1

Comment: Nothing changed. My function add_stream do something like that http://pastebin.com/kx6mCvX6

Comment: have a look at this here: http://pastebin.com/Bc8tCgrC its for h264 though see if you can get some pointers from it.

Comment: I think problem is with avio_open. Im looking at it source code and it calls ffurl_alloc(...) and that function can return AVERROR_PROTOCOL_NOT_FOUND. It happens when url_find_protocols(const char *filename) fails, so maybe i am using wrong url? Thats only parameter, any AV struct is not used here. URL i am using is: "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8765/live.sdp" Oh one more thing, stream that iam getting from camera is too rtsp stream. I can without problems read frames, convert to openCV frames and display them.

Comment: did you try this with vlc "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8765/live.sdp" running this url and see if you are able to play the stream?

Comment: Hmm, maybe i am misunderstanding something, but i thought that first i have to stream from my application before i can open it in VLC

Comment: i thought you are trying to read from rtsp://127.0.0.1:8765/live.sdp and then do some opencv process and restream to another url? is that correct?

Comment: I am reading from IPCamera (addr: "rtsp://username:password@ip_addr:port/path/media.amp") then processing frames with opencv (for tests i am drawing red rectangle on every frame) and result i want to restream to "rtsp://127.0.0.1:8765/live.sdp". Reading, processing and converting from cv::mat to AVFrame works.